# ProgrammingError at /grammar_correction/ text to correct SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, django-models

## I am working on a spell_grammer_check Django API with to end points spell_correction and grammar_correction. the spelling correction function return me results successfully but for grammar_correction it gines me ProgrammingError at /grammar_correction/ text to correct SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.`import sqlite3

```
typimport sqlite3
from django.http import JsonResponse
from whoosh.index import open_dir
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
from whoosh.qparser import plugins
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import heapq
import re

ix = open_dir('C:/Users/Na Da/Documents/Final Semester/final project/myproject/indexed_unigram')
searcher = ix.searcher()
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Na Da/Documents/Final Semester/final project/myproject/bigramDatabase")
c = conn.cursor()

def word_search(word):
    query_parser = QueryParser("ngram", schema=ix.schema)
    query = query_parser.parse(word)
    count = 0
    word = ' '
    for r in  searcher.search(query,limit = 1):
        count = r['count']
    return count

def  word_suggestions_special_char(word,pos):
    replaces = [( L + c + R[1:]) for L, R in  [(word[:pos],word[pos:])] if R for c in  'اأإ' for word in (L + c + R[1:],)]
    word_prob={}
    for w in replaces:
        count = word_search(w)
        if count!=0:
            word_prob[w] = count
    return heapq.nlargest(1, word_prob,key=word_prob.get)


def word_suggestions(word):
    my_parser = QueryParser("ngram", schema=ix.schema)
    my_parser.add_plugin(plugins.FuzzyTermPlugin())
    query = my_parser.parse(word+'~')
    results = searcher.search(query,limit = None)
    word_prob={}
    for r in  results:
        word_prob[r['ngram']] = r['count'] 
    return  heapq.nlargest(5, word_prob,key=word_prob.get)

def spelling_correction(request, sentence):
    suggestions = {}
    re.sub('[?.",;:]', '', (sentence)) + ' '
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        if word == 'و':
            continue
        count = word_search(word)
        if count<1000:
             suggestions[word] = word_suggestions(word)
        else:
            if word [0] == 'ا' and word[2] =='ا' :
                suggestions[word] = word_suggestions_special_char(word,2)
                continue
            if word[0] =='ا' :
                suggestions[word] = word_suggestions_special_char(word,0)
                continue
            suggestions[word] = word
    return JsonResponse(suggestions)

def get_corrections(word):
    query = "SELECT word2, count FROM mytable WHERE word1 = ?"
    c.execute(query, (word,))
    bigrams = c.fetchall()
    total_count = sum([count for _, count in bigrams])
    probabilities = [(w2, count / total_count) for w2, count in bigrams]
    probabilities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    suggestions = [w2 for w2, _ in probabilities[:10]]
    return  suggestions 

def get_bigram_counts( word1, word2):
    c = conn.cursor()
    query = 'SELECT* FROM mytable WHERE word1=? AND word2=?;'
    c.execute(query, (word1, word2))
    count = c.fetchall()
    if count:
        return count
    else:
        return 0


def get_corrections_with_thirdWord(word,word3):
    query = "SELECT word2, count FROM mytable WHERE word1 = ?"
    c.execute(query, (word,))
    bigrams = c.fetchall()
    results=[]
    for w in bigrams:
        r = get_bigram_counts( w[0], word3)
        if r:
            results.append (w)
    total_count = sum([count for _, count in results])
    probabilities = [(w2, count / total_count) for w2, count in results]
    probabilities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    suggestions = [w2 for w2, _ in probabilities[:]]
    return  suggestions 

def grammar_correction(request,sentence):
    words =sentence.split()
    corrected_sentence = []
    if len(words)==1:
        return sentence
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result = get_bigram_counts( words[i], words[i+1])
        if result:
            if i ==len(words)-2:
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i+1])
                return  ' '.join(corrected_sentence)
            corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
        else:
            if(i==len(words)-2):
                suggestions =get_corrections(words[i])
                matched_word = max( suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i+1],w))
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
                corrected_sentence.append(matched_word)
                return' '.join(corrected_sentence)
            corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
            suggestions =get_corrections_with_thirdWord(words[i],words[i+2])
            if  suggestions:  
                matched_word = max( suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i+1],w))
                words[i+1] = matched_word
            else:
                corrected_sentence +=words[i+1]
                continue
    return JsonResponse(' '.join(corrected_sentence))
```

I cant get where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`SQLite` is being accessed from multiple threads simultaneously, it is not thread-safe, `conn` and `c` objects are global and shared among threads.

Lets make sure to create a new `SQLite` connection and cursor inside each `view` function.

```
import sqlite3
from django.http import JsonResponse
from whoosh.index import open_dir
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
from whoosh.qparser import plugins
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import heapq
import re

ix = open_dir('C:/Users/Na Da/Documents/Final Semester/final project/myproject/indexed_unigram')
searcher = ix.searcher()

def grammar_correction(request, sentence):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("C:/Users/Na Da/Documents/Final Semester/final project/myproject/bigramDatabase")
    c = conn.cursor()

    words = sentence.split()
    corrected_sentence = []
    if len(words) == 1:
        return sentence
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result = get_bigram_counts(words[i], words[i + 1], c)
        if result:
            if i == len(words) - 2:
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i + 1])
                return ' '.join(corrected_sentence)
            corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
        else:
            if i == len(words) - 2:
                suggestions = get_corrections(words[i], c)
                matched_word = max(suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i + 1], w))
                corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
                corrected_sentence.append(matched_word)
                return ' '.join(corrected_sentence)
            corrected_sentence.append(words[i])
            suggestions = get_corrections_with_thirdWord(words[i], words[i + 2], c)
            if suggestions:
                matched_word = max(suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i + 1], w))
                words[i + 1] = matched_word
            else:
                corrected_sentence += words[i + 1]
                continue
    return JsonResponse(' '.join(corrected_sentence))


def get_corrections(word, cursor):
    query = "SELECT word2, count FROM mytable WHERE word1 = ?"
    cursor.execute(query, (word,))
    bigrams = cursor.fetchall()
    total_count = sum([count for _, count in bigrams])
    probabilities = [(w2, count / total_count) for w2, count in bigrams]
    probabilities.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    suggestions = [w2 for w2, _ in probabilities[:10]]
    return suggestions


def get_bigram_counts(word1, word2, cursor):
    query = 'SELECT* FROM mytable WHERE word1=? AND word2=?;'
    cursor.execute(query, (word1, word2))
    count = cursor.fetchall()
    if count:
        return count
    else:
        return 0


def get_corrections_with_thirdWord(word, word3, cursor):
    query = "SELECT word2, count FROM mytable WHERE word1 = ?"
    cursor.execute(query, (word,))
    bigrams = cursor.fetchall()
    results = []
    for w in bigrams:
        r = get_bigram_counts(w[0], word3, cursor)
        if r:
            results.append(w)
```

Comment: After trying this it leads to another error that  ValueError at /grammar_correction/
max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: This might happen in those 2 lines matched_word = max(suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i+1],w))

and

matched_word = max(suggestions, key=lambda w: fuzz.ratio(words[i+1],w))

Comment: do you have any ideas to solve this